# How would I add the sum of a nested list of numbers using recursion? How would I do it using iteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

I need to write two functions that find the sum of a nested list of numbers, one that uses iteration and one that uses recursion.

I have written two functions that successfully find the sum of a non-nested list of numbers, but I'm unsure how to make them go through nested lists.

This is what I have so far:

```
def iterative_sum(ls:list):
    max = len(ls)
    i = 0
    num_sum = 0
    while i < max:
        
            num_sum += ls[i]
            i += 1
    return num_sum

def recursive_sum(ls:list):
    if len(ls)==0:
        return 0
    else:
        return ls[0] + recursive_sum(ls[1:])

num_list = [1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 10, 5]

print("Iterative sum:", iterative_sum(num_list))

print ("Recursive sum:", recursive_sum(num_list))
```

It works great for the non-nested list, but I need it to work if my list was something like this as well:

`num_list = [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, [[6, 7], 8]], 9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work for arbitrarily nested lists:

```
def iterative_sum(ls):
    # ls = ls[:]  # if you want it to be non-destructive
    s = 0
    while ls:
        last = ls.pop()
        if isinstance(last, int):
            s += last
        else:
            ls.extend(last)
    return s

>>> iterative_sum([1, 2, [3, 4], [5, [[6, 7], 8]], 9])
45

def recursive_sum(ls):
    if isinstance(ls, int):
        return ls
    # return sum(map(recursive_sum, ls))
    s = 0
    for x in ls:
        s += recursive_sum(x)
    return s

>>> recursive_sum([1, 2, [3, 4], [5, [[6, 7], 8]], 9])
45
```

And another approach using recursion without any iteration and without slicing:

```
def recursive_sum(ls, i=0):
    if not isinstance(ls, list):
        return ls
    if i == len(ls):
        return 0
    return recursive_sum(ls[i]) + recursive_sum(ls, i+1)
```

Comment: Your recursive function, while technically recursive, may not be what the OP's instructor has in mind because it actually iterates through the given list. Usually assignments that ask students to write a recursive function come with the restriction of not using any loop.

Comment: True. I will leave it as is since you show that already. Also, something just itches me the wrong way when I see repeated slicing =) I don't think it should be taught ever, so I added another approach without slicing or iteration.

Comment: Right, I went the slicing route because of the OP's sample code. It's easy to understand due to its pseudocode-like appearance but is otherwise inefficient and should never be used for anything other than learning the fundamentals of recursion.

Comment: Another way to make it non-destructive: `ls = [ls]`

Answer (score 0):

With an iterative approach, you can enqueue items in a sub-list into the main list for further iterations while you iterate over the main list:

```
def iterative_sum(lst):
    s = 0
    for i in lst:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            lst += i
        else:
            s += i
    return s
```

With a recursive approach, you can separate the first item from the rest of the items in the list for recursive calls, until the given object is either an empty list or not a list:

```
def recursive_sum(lst):
    if not isinstance(lst, list):
        return lst
    if lst:
        return recursive_sum(lst[0]) + recursive_sum(lst[1:])
    return 0
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/AZqYWX